# Having trouble understanding currying

Tags: haskell

In theory I understand what currying is, but in practice i'm puzzled with what I get in ghci.

Let's look at the example below. First here are the types I'll be using.

```
Prelude> :t f
f :: a -> a -> a -> a

Prelude> :t x
x :: char

Prelude> :t y
y :: char -> char

Prelude> :t z
z :: char -> char -> char
```

By doing the following, can you explain to me how I get these types?

```
Prelude> :t f x
f x :: a -> a -> a

Prelude> :t f y
f y :: (char -> char) -> (char -> char) -> char -> char

Prelude> :t f z
f z
  :: (char -> char -> char)
     -> (char -> char -> char) -> char -> char -> char
```

Comment: Mind that `char` is in lowercase, so it is a type variable, not a `Char`acter.

Comment: I actually meant Char, but i'm happy that I've made this mistake. It added some flavor to my question that may help people starting on Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**: the `char` as type parameter, is *not* a `Char`acter. Since it starts with a lowercase, it is a type parameter. The type of `x` is thus `x :: b` as well.

A function in Haskell has *exactly* one parameter. If one writes:

```
f :: a -> a -> a -> a
```

then this is actually short for:

```
f :: a -> (a -> (a -> a))
```

So `f` takes a parameter of type `a`, and returns a function of type `a -> (a -> a)`.

## `f x :: a -> a -> a`

In case we want to derive the type of `f x`, we can see that:

```
f :: a -> (a -> (a -> a))
x :: b
```

since `x` is the parameter of a function application with `f` as function, it thus means that the type of `x` (`b`) should be the same as the type of the parameter of the function (`a`). So it means that `a ~ b` (`a` is the same type as `b`).

The type of the result the type of the output of the function, so `a -> (a -> a)`, or `b -> (b -> b)`. But since `b` is not more specific than `a`, both are fine.

A less verbose expression of `a -> (a -> a)` is `a -> a -> a`.

## `f y :: (b -> b) -> (b -> b) -> b -> b`

So what about `f y`? As ingredients, we have:

```
f :: a -> (a -> (a -> a))
y :: b -> b
```

Since `y` is the parameter of a function application with `f`, the type of `y` (`b -> b`) is the same type as `a`, so that means that `a ~ (b -> b)`.

The type of output is thus:

```
f y :: a -> (a -> a)
```

or when we convert this:

```
f y :: (b -> b) -> ((b -> b) -> (b -> b))
```

or less verbose:

```
f y :: (b -> b) -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

## `f z :: (b -> b -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> b -> b -> b`

As ingredients we have:

```
f :: a -> (a -> (a -> a))
z :: b -> (b -> b)
```

So that means that for a function application `f z`, we thus have `a ~ (b -> (b -> b))`. The result is that the type of `f z` is:

```
f z :: a -> (a -> a)
```

or when we convert `a` to `(b -> (b -> b))`:

```
f z :: (b -> (b -> b)) -> ((b -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> (b -> b)))
```

or less verbose:

```
f z :: (b -> b -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> b -> b -> b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f :: a -> a -> a -> a
```

is read as

```
f :: a -> (a -> a -> a)
```

which means: `f` takes an argument `a` and returns a function `a -> a -> a`. Since `a` is a type variable, `f` is polymorphic, so the type `a` will be chosen to be whatever matches with the argument of `f`,

Consequently, for any typeable expression `w`, the expression `f w` has type

```
(type of w) -> (type of w) -> (type of w)
```

This is precisely what happens in all the examples provided in the question.